# Como puedo realizar consultas con webservice ajax ?

Tags: html, ajax, django, webservice

Que tal a todos ? Estoy trabajando en un proyecto, donde el backend debe hacerse con Django y el frontend con HTML, pero para que estos dos se comuniquen tengo que usar webservice ajax y eso es algo que no sé :( Si me pudieran dar una mano de como tendría que hacer, se lo agradecería muchisimo.

Comment: Hola podrias mostrar que tienes hasta ahora. Ya tienes el backend?

Comment: Si, ya tengo el backend, no sé nomas si acá se puede subir archivos :/ Pero el html lo que me hace falta y unir ese con Django.
El tema es que llegué a usar el template de Django y hasta ahí pude guardar todos los datos, no pude seguir más de eso (editar y ver y eliminar los datos), porque me pidieron hacer como les dije y la verdad que ni idea no tengo de como comenzar jajajaja si saben de algun tutorial que pueda leer, me vendría bien

Comment: Hola Walter! Bienvenido, te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que obtengas respuestas de calidad de parte de la comunidad y que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo con con los **template de django** puedes hacer el "html que dices" y ahí hacer todas las operaciones que desees.
mira su documentación:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/language/#templates
Y si no te queda claro mira estos tutoriales que a mi me ayudaron aprender lo básico de django:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJseXY2sup8&list=PLpOqH6AE0tNgL7Jg9Kx4SdfA5_oK6292j

Ahora, si te han pedido separar backend con frontend te recomiendo usar **django rest framework** que sirve para poder crear servicios desde básicos hasta muy potentes:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Espero te sirva de algo. Un abrazo!